# Hive reading while inserting

Tags: hadoop, hive

What would happen if I'm trying to read from a hive table , while concurrently there is someone inserting into the hive table.

Does it lock the files while querying into it, or does it do a dirty read???

Answer (score 0):

- Hadoop is meant for parallel proceesing. So in a cluster parallel querying can be done on a hive table.
- While some data is being inserted in the table if another user queries the same table, the files are not locked, rather a job is accepted is put to execution.
- Now if the new data insert is successful before the second query
  is      processed the the result    of the second query will
  acknowledge the       inserted data.
- Note:    In most cases data    insertion takes lesser time      than
  querying a    table because    while querying MR jobs are created and
  are run in    backend

Comment: Is this behavior in Hive 0.13 or 0.14 ?